# Compare CustomerID from two tables and determine who made the most purchases

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL, coming from Python, and having a hard time understanding SQL syntax. I have one table called "**Purchases**", and a second table, below the first, called "**Customers**".

I want to `SELECT` the LastName of the Customer with the *most* Purchases (which can be counted in `PurchaseID`). I have figured out how to aggregate Purchase count by Last Name, but I can't figure out how to return the single Customer `LastName` with the *most* purchases. Lastly, I'm not sure if I'm doing this in the most intuitive way? I'm happy to receive feedback.

| PurchaseID | CustomerID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 5 |
| 7 | 5 |
| 8 | 4 |
| 9 | 3 |
| 10 | 2 |

| LastName | CustomerID |
| --- | --- |
| Davis | 1 |
| Smith | 2 |
| Tran | 3 |
| Washington | 4 |
| Lopez | 5 |

```sql
SELECT t2.LastName, COUNT(t1.CustomerID) AS purchase_count
FROM Purchases t1
LEFT JOIN Customers t2 ON 
t1.CustomerID = t2.CustomerID
GROUP BY t2.LastName
```

returns

| LastName | purchase_count |
| --- | --- |
| Davis | 1 |
| Smith | 2 |
| Lopez | 3 |
| Tran | 2 |
| Washington | 2 |

Comment: What do you expect if more than one person shares the same count?

Comment: `ORDER BY purchase_count DESC LIMIT 1` (and solve what to do when there will be more users with the most puchases).

Comment: What if there are two customers with three purchases?

Comment: Thank you, and Sorry, I don't see what you mean - only CustomerID 5 has 3 purchases?

Comment: What if Tran has three purchases as well? Who should be in the result?

Comment: In this case, I suppose I would want the query to return both Tran and Lopez, but would need to solve for how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is using `ORDER BY purchase_count DESC LIMIT 1` at the end of your query as mentioned. However, it will return always just one customer even if there are more customers with the highest purchase count.

If you would like to return all customers with the highest purchase count then use the following query.

```
SELECT t2.LastName, COUNT(t1.CustomerID) AS purchase_count
FROM Purchases t1
LEFT JOIN Customers t2 
  ON t1.CustomerID = t2.CustomerID
GROUP BY t2.LastName
HAVING COUNT(t1.CustomerID) >= all(
    SELECT COUNT(t1.CustomerID) AS purchase_count
    FROM Purchases t1
    GROUP BY t1.CustomerID
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I will  read about `HAVING` and `all` so that I can understand this more clearly

Comment: @seh33 you are welcome :)